# Texstudio configured with xelatex - pdflatex throws errors

Tags: xetex, pdftex, texstudio

I'm curently writing my thesis.
Before I was using pdflatex, but then due to problems with UTF8 encoding I changed to Xelatex.

Now, I randomly get errors with cryptic messages from pdflatex:

```
Process started: xelatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "Document_name".tex

Process exited normally



Process started: xelatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "Document_name".tex

Process exited normally



Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "PZABny".tex

Error: Command crashed: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "PZABny".tex

Process exited with error(s)

Process started: pdflatex.exe -interaction=nonstopmode -ini "&pdflatex hdGrtjw \dump"

Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "KuJYtC".tex

Process started: pdflatex.exe -interaction=nonstopmode -ini "&pdflatex hNcbAeZ \dump"

Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "rlDtFI".tex

Process started: pdflatex.exe -interaction=nonstopmode -ini "&pdflatex hkMDXdn \dump"

Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "DMsuyD".tex

Process started: pdflatex.exe -interaction=nonstopmode -ini "&pdflatex huSKdPe \dump"

Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "Ylngba".tex

Process exited normally

Process exited normally

Process exited normally

Error: Command crashed: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "KuJYtC".tex

Process exited with error(s)

Error: Command crashed: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "rlDtFI".tex

Process exited with error(s)

Process exited normally

Error: Command crashed: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "DMsuyD".tex

Process exited with error(s)

Error: Command crashed: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "Ylngba".tex

Process exited with error(s)
```

I suspect, it's due to some wrong build settings. Searching for the weird filenames e.g. "PZABny".tex didn't bring up anything at all.
I don't want to randomly play around, so I'll add my build settings here:
[image]

[image]

Do you know, why pdflatex is still randomly active? It just runs by itself, calls miktex (i need to confirm package install) and then crashes...

Comment: I know nothing about texstudio but your pdf chain is pdftex based not xetex based according to the image you show

Comment: What command sequence are you starting when you get these errors? The build & view?

Comment: @ChaokangTai I don't start any command sequence, that's the weird part. I just randomly starts.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That might be the culprit, but I didn't know if that was actually the problem. 
By the way - what is the "Asymptote PDF chain"?

Comment: you haven't said what you do to start the process so it is impossible to guess. You have shown the customisation of the menu options but not said which menu option you choose. asymptote is a separate program to generate diagrams, similar to you could do with tikz or metapost, there are examples on this site.

Comment: Ok, I have now followed the behaviour for a while, and I realized, that it is probably due to the preview option in Texstudio. (Options --> Configure TeXstudio --> Preview)
If I understand that correctly, just hovering over certain things will give a preview. 
Apparently xelatex and pdflatex don't work together here.

Unfortunately I can't change the command to xelatex. I'm trying now with dvipng. Maye that works.

Comment: ok, as the error messages now point to dvipng I'm pretty sure, I found the culprit.
How can I turn off the automatic preview, or make it work?

Comment: Tried to solve the problem the following way:
Go to Options -> Configure TeXstudio -> Preview. Set Auto Update to never.
Unfortunately, this didn't stop the preview function.